# NSUserNotification change Notification image/logo on a per-notification basis

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nsusernotification

When scheduling a NSUserNotification for delivery to NSUserNotificationCenter, is there any way to set the image/logo that shows up alongside the notification on a per-notification basis?

I would like a slightly different logo to show up for different types of notification. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mountain Lion it is not there.
If you wish you can request it here https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set the Image in OSX mavericks this way.

In the AppDelegate.h file add the line:

```
@property (copy) NSImage *contentImage NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, NA);
```

In the AppDelegate.m

```
notification.contentImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't change the logo but adds another image. But that's the best public API we have.